# match 'article' in url RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

building a site which has content for each section.

urls range from;
/work/
/work/print/
/work/print/folders etc.

however, at any point a user can click on an article so;
/work/article/1066
/work/print/article/1066
/work/print/folders/article/1066

using .htaccess i need to detect when there is 'article' in the url and set some different variables.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$ 
sets  index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3&level4=$4
```

but if 'article/([0-9-]+)' is in the url, say /work/print/article/1066 return 
    index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&articleID=1066

basically the amount of levels will always be different but i'd like to return those as needed.
another example would /work/print/folder/archive/article/1066 return

```
index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3&level4=$4&articleID=1066
```

any help appreciated! Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end i just did it manually! (though would prefer a more expansive solutions)

```
# MENU ###

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$  index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$  index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$  index.php?level1=$1 [L]


###  WITH ARTICLE  ###


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/article/([0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$$  index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3&articleID=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/article/([0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$$  index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&articleID=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/article/([0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$  index.php?level1=$1&articleID=$2 [L]


RewriteRule ^$  index.php?level1=home [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to do the level detection in your php script.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/article/(\d+)$ index.php?levelsUri=$1&articleID=$2
```

You can then parse the "levelsUri" request value and detect the levels in your php script.